# Switch loop with continuing power to supply an outlet

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture, contractors

Attached is a diagram of what I’m trying to make sure I wire correctly.

- I have 12/2 wire coming from panel to light fixture,
- 12/3 wire with red going from light fixture to a double toggle switch,
- 12/2 wire from same light fixture that I want to stay hot and run to an outlet.
- And then one 12/2 wire from a another light fixture going to the same double toggle switch.

Any help would be appreciated

[image: switch loop diagram]

![wire diagram][2]][2]

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing all the wires attached to the switches? There are a number of different possible configurations.

Comment: Yeah I’m not sure why it didn’t post the picture. I just made an edit with a poorly drawn diagram. Hopefully it will show up. Thank you

Comment: I was actually trying to edit it when you put in the edit that included the diagram. Try uploading the other picture again. If it doesn't seem to display, save the edit after the upload anyway and I can probably make it work. Problem is that I can't see the raw code of the previous version of the post, just the formatted (which doesn't show the img url).

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking. The wire routing looks reasonable. The left light uses a switched hot on black from one switch and neutral that's been passed through. The one toward the right uses the switched hot on red from the other switch and neutral. Straightforward enough... Are you asking how the dual switch is wired, or how the box for the right-hand light is wired, or something else?

Comment: That just ended up with 2 copies of the same picture. Looking for a picture of the actual wiring on the switch - i.e., remove the switch cover plate, carefully pull out the switch but don't disconnect any wires, take a picture (sometimes 2 or 3 needed from different angles) and upload that picture(s).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, I’ll get a few actual pictures this afternoon and post. Unfortunately the light and switch are not connected.

Comment: @keshlam, I apologize I should’ve been more clear. Basically all the wire was run but nothing is connected. I was hoping to know how to wire the switch and the wires coming into the light fixture with the power source. Thanks

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I truly appreciate it! Got it wired and everything is good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to wire this is actually simple.

See the attached diagram with location markings:

At all locations:    Tie all grounds together with the ground to the light fixture or switch or outlet. (A pigtail can be used for that as well)

At Location A: Tie all the whites together with the white or neutral from the light fixture, or pigtail.

Tie all the blacks together. Nothing to the light fixture

The red wire ties to the black or Hot to the light fixture.

At Location B: The black coming from location A gets attached to the line in side of the switch, ( most single pole double switches have a single screw on one side.)

The red goes to one screw on the other side of the switch.  The remaining black  goes to the second screw on that side and feeds the light at location C.

The whites get tied together.

At location C: The standard black to hot,  white to neutral,  ground to ground applies as it does to the outlet at location D.
[image: Scheme]

Answer (score 3):

Based on a comment, this is "wires in place, no devices connected". Which makes things easy. The key is to match wire color to function, changing color as needed.

Standard US non-metallic cables (NM, a.k.a., Romex) are:

- 2-wire (plus bare ground), also called /2, black/white
- 3-wire (plus bare ground), also called /3, black/red/white

While not required (well, sort of - neutral must be white, but white is not always neutral), a way to make this easy is to *always* use:

- Black = hot (i.e., *always* hot, not switched)
- White = neutral
- Red = switched hot
- Bare wire or green = ground (in cables this will always be bare, but switches and light fixtures sometimes have a green ground wire instead of a ground screw)

If you have 3-way switches or certain other things then it gets more complicated, but that's all we need here.

- All grounds, together, always. Plus if you have metal boxes, as you should, incoming ground wires go first to the box. If you have metal boxes then switches with metal yokes and better quality ("self-grounding") receptacles don't need a ground wire as they ground automatically through the metal box.
- Hot connection on each light fixture is **red**. If it is a screw terminal, just remember that. If it is a wire, put red tape on it. Since it is "red", it is now *switched hot*.
- Simple switches don't care about "hot" vs. "switched hot" and don't use neutral. If a switch does care about "hot" (or "line" or "incoming") vs. "switched hot" (or "load" or "outgoing") then mark switched hot with red tape (or if it is a screw, just remember that).
- The black wire from the top switch to the light fixture should get red tape on both ends to turn it (virtually) into a red wire.

And then you just wire up:

- All white/neutral in every box all together. That includes wires, switches (if they use neutral), light fixtures and receptacles.
- All hots in every box all together. In the case of the double switch, it might have two separate hot screws (in which case you connect the incoming hot to two short black "pigtails" and connect one pigtail to each screw) or one "common" screw.
- Red wire to the "switched hot" connection on each switch.
- Red wire to the "switched hot" connection on each light fixture.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your question is what happens inside each of the two electrical boxes in this particular arrangement?

At the right-hand lamp:

- All blacks (hot) are connected together with a wire nut or equivalent.
- All whites (neutral), plus a "pigtail" for the lamp, are connected together with a wire nut or equivalent.
- The lamp is connected between red (switched hot) and the white pigtail (neutral).

At the dual switch:

- Both whites (neutral) are connected together with a wire nut or equivalent.
- The black from the lamp (hot) is connected to one side of both switches.
- The red (switched hot) is connected to the other side of one switch.
- The black from the left-hand lamp (switched hot) is connected to the other side of the other switch.

At the left-hand light:

- The lamp is connected between black (switched hot) and white (neutral).

Quick sloppy schematic sketch:

[image: Schematic showing dual switch to two lamps, one as switch loop]